# SQL Query works fine in MySQL, but giving error in PostgreSql

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am trying to access data from two different databases MySql & PostgreSQL,
Below query is working in MySql but gives an error

```
ERROR:  column "sales.item_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 2:        sales.item_id,
               ^
```

when running on PostgreSQL server

```
SELECT  
       sales.item_id,
       sales.sales_date,
       sales.city_id,
       geography.city,
       geography.state,
       count(quantity) as QTY_SOLD,
       price,
      (cogs * count(quantity)) AS TOTAL_PURCHASE,
      (price * count(quantity)) AS TOTAL_SALES,
      ((price * count(quantity)) - (cogs * count(quantity))) AS PROFIT
       FROM sales JOIN geography ON sales.city_id = geography.city_id
       GROUP BY
       geography.city
       ORDER BY PROFIT DESC;
```

Any suggested correction in written query?

Comment: IN most sql dialects all non aggregated columns must appear in the group by clause, mysql is less fussy (As long is only_full_group_by is not set) but the non aggregated columns may be indeterminate depending on functional dependency.

Comment: So how can I achieve the result? As if I add all those columns in group by, what I want to achive fails.

Comment: You should publish sample data and expected outcome as text or to a fiddle and an explanation of what you are trying to do (the mysql query is too dubious for me to reverse engineer intent). And do publish your amended query.

Comment: @ShubhamJain if you add every non-aggregated field involved in a select expression to the `group by`, the query should not longer fail... at least not with that particular error.

Comment: BTW I wouldn't expect the fixed postgresql query to give the same result as the mysql query so the fixed postgresql query may be correct as coded..

Comment: Add `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` to `sql_mode` in MySQL, then MySQL will likely throw an equivalent error for the query.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html  as far as suggestions to rewrite the query, remove all of the non-aggregate expressions from the SELECT list that don't appear in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: One way to explain what is going on here is by asking a question, so it becomes apparent a RDBMS would be left wondering the same... "Which sale_date for each city are you actually expecting to receive?"